# Get the current date and time with milliseconds with only the standard library in C++

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14, c++17

I'm trying to print a timestamp like this.

```
2018-05-24T20:16:07.339271
```

I don't want to use Boost or any third party libraries. I want to only use the standard library. I'm using Clang 6, so I should be able to use C++ 17 if necessary.

I started looking at `chrono` and have something like this.

```
auto now = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
```

But, I'm unsure how to get the datetime format that I want from above.

Comment: It seems this is probably possible, perhaps with [`std::ctime`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/c/ctime) or [`std::strftime`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/c/strftime)

Comment: Until C++20 comes with chrono additions, there's always [`std::put_time`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/put_time) too.

Comment: `high_resolution_clock` has no portable relationship to a human-defined calendar.

Answer (score 3):

The following code uses standard C++ only. The data contained in ***loc_time** and **milli_secs** can be used to produce the desired output in local time. To get the output in UTC, use std::gmtime instead of std::localtime.

```
// get actual system time
const auto now = std::chrono::system_clock::now();

// get seconds since 1970/1/1 00:00:00 UTC
const auto sec_utc = std::chrono::system_clock::to_time_t(now);

// get pointer to tm struct (not thread safe!)
const auto loc_time = std::localtime(&sec_utc);

// get time_point from sec_utc (note: no milliseconds)
const auto now_s = std::chrono::system_clock::from_time_t(sec_utc);

// get milliseconds (difference between now and now_s
const auto milli_secs = std::chrono::duration<double, std::milli>(now - now_s).count() * .001;
```

Answer (score 2):

guess your best bet is using [`std::localtime`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/c/localtime) + [`std::put_time`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/put_time)

Comment: Neither of those allow for milliseconds as far as I know, only seconds.

Comment: @RetiredNinja, Fair, you could do something like `(duration_cast<milliseconds>(time) % 1s).count()` to get milliseconds. That probably needs a bit of tweaking.

Comment: After a bit of time to actually try it, milliseconds can be obtained with the above, but `time.time_since_epoch()` to get a duration and optionally replacing `duration_cast` with `floor`, `ceil`, or `round`, depending on what you want.

Answer (score -3):

```
standard library c++ does not provide a proper date type, so you can use   
structs and functions from c which is inherited on c++. <ctime>  header
file need to include in c++ program. i think below code will help you.

    time_t now = time(0);
    cout<<now<<endl;
    tm *lt = localtime(&now);
```